# Arithmetic mean of $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$ with an $n-1$ number of $1's$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Okay, here's the question in a nutshell (The entire question is much longer but I've simplified it to the equation below, I'll explain what it is):

$$1-\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n^5}\right) + (n-1)}{n}$$

There are $n$ numbers of which $1$ of them is $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$  and all the others are $1's$. How much  is the arithmetic mean of these numbers less than $1$?

First of all, to me, the equation above seems impossible to simplify, but it might be easy for some of you, so could you show me step-by-step how to simplify it?

Second of all, if it IS indeed impossible, where have I gone wrong at interpreting the question? I suspect I did something wrong with the first half of the question, so please point out where I've gone wrong (IF impossible)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "solve"? You want to get a formula in terms of $n$ and ... you figured it out.  You can *simplify* it further as heropup did in their answer.  But... that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking too hard.

The actual sum is $\underbrace{1+1+...... + 1}_{n-1\text{ ones}} + (1- \frac 1{n^5})=$

$\underbrace{1+1+......+1 (+ 1}_{n \text{ ones}}- \frac 1{n^5})=$

$n -\frac 1 {n^5}$.

So the mean is $\frac {n-\frac 1{n^5}} n = 1 - \frac 1{n^6}$.

And how much less than $1$ is that?

Well, it *literally* is $\frac 1{n^6}$ less than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$1 - \frac{(1 - n^{-5}) + (n-1)}{n} = 1 - \frac{n - n^{-5}}{n} = 1 - 1 + n^{-6} = \frac{1}{n^6}.$$  I'm not sure what else you need to do.

Comment: The transition I'm particularly unfamiliar with is the first one, how do you get from $(1-n^{-5})+(n-1)$ to $n-n^{-5}$?

Comment: You are unfamiliar with $1-1 = 0$?

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now, thanks @fleablood

Comment: @AlexJaynMF $\require{cancel}(1 - n^{-5}) + (n - 1) \equiv 1 - n^{-5} + n - 1 \equiv \cancel{1} - n^{-5}+ n - \cancel{1} \equiv -n^{-5} + n \equiv n - n^{-5}$.